# "Table does not exist" when I try to insert data with Hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using Hibernate framework the XML way, in a Spring Boot project. I chose PostgreSQL as DBMS. I've set the configuration files but I'm getting "**could not extract ResultSet**" message whenever I try to insert data. The exception i;m getting is

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "employees" does not exist

I tested connection with Intellij and it was fine. I think something is wrong with my hbm file.

---

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MyDB</property>
    <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <mapping resource="employees.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
```

---

**employees.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.company.entities.Employee" table="Employees" schema="public" >
    <id name="eid" type = "int" column = "eid">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="name" type="java.lang.String" />
    <property name="description" column="description" type="java.lang.String" />
    <property name="salary" column="salary" type="java.lang.Double" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

**EmployeeDAO.java**

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDAO
{
static Session sessionObj;


private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory()
{
    return new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
}

public void insertEmp(List<Employee> allEmployees)
{
    sessionObj = buildSessionFactory().openSession();
    sessionObj.beginTransaction();
    for (Employee emp: allEmployees)
    {
        sessionObj.save(prod);
    }
    sessionObj.getTransaction().commit();
    if(sessionObj != null)
    {
        sessionObj.close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You have to tell Hibernate to generate Tables automatically, have a look https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Comment: I've manually created my db and tables. Why would I want to generate Tables automatically? Not sure what you mean. Anyway, I tried  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> and hibernate creates a new table instead of using the existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error message mentions "employee" whereas in your mapping, you are talking about "Employee" ... i think it might be a case issue:

https://blog.xojo.com/2016/09/28/about-postgresql-case-sensitivity/

---

employees.hbm.xml file needs to change from

```
<class name="com.company.entities.Employee" table="Employees" schema="public" >
```

to

```
<class name="com.company.entities.Employee" table="`Employees`" schema="public" >
```